# Is there a faster way to sum Xarray dataset variables?

Tags: python, dataset, python-xarray

This is my first ever stack exchange question, so I hope I'm doing this correctly.

I am trying to sum together a few xarray variables in a dataset. Each variable has the same dimensions. The code looks essentially like this:

```
def add_variables(xarray_dataset, listofvars):
    data = 0
    for var in listofvars:
        data = data + dset[var][:,-1,:] # slice of each variable
    return data 

summed_variables = add_variables(dset, ['varname1, varname2'])
```

However, this takes forever to run. Does anyone have a suggestion for a faster way to go about this?
Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried `xarray_dataset.sum()`? If that's not right, could you post a fully reproducible example?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`to_array`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_array.html?#xarray-dataset-to-array) method to stack the variables along a new dimension (which is by default named "variable") and then take the sum over this dimension. You can select variables and slice them beforehand if necessary.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr

# Create dummy dataset
ds = xr.Dataset(
    {var: (("x", "y", "z"), np.random.rand(5, 3, 2)) for var in "abcde"}
)

# Sum over (a slice of some of the) variables
vars_to_sum = ["a", "c", "d"]
summed_variables = ds[vars_to_sum].isel(y=-1).to_array().sum("variable")
```

I think that this is a lot easier than your custom function although it is not faster in my comparison<sup>1</sup>:

```
%timeit add_variables(ds, vars_to_sum)
464 µs ± 591 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit ds[vars_to_sum].isel(y=-1).to_array().sum("variable")
660 µs ± 12.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

However, for this small dataset, both of them are pretty fast so the difference is not noticeable. I don't know what your dataset looks like – it would probably help if you could share some more information about the data in order to diagnose performance issues.

<sup>1</sup> Note that I had to change your function a little bit to make it run – the name of the dataset in the function header and body were not consistent:

```
def add_variables(xarray_dataset, listofvars):
    data = 0
    for var in listofvars:
        # changed dset to xarray_dataset in the following line
        data = data + xarray_dataset[var][:,-1,:]
    return data
```