# Pythonic way to iteratively add 2D DataArrays in DataSet without losing dimensions, using Xarray?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, python-xarray, iterable

I've got a bunch of xarray DataSets consisting of a variable number of 2D DataArrays, all the same size (lat/lon dims).I'd like to get the sum of *some* of the DataArrays in the Datasets, without losing any dimensions.

I found a way to do this, but it seems like there should be an built in function/ more pythonic way to do this. Can it be done in a single line for loop or using an iterable? It seems most summing functions force you to lose a dimension.

```
# Build a fake dataset that is way, way smaller than what I have, with lat, lon as dims: 
ds=xr.Dataset()
lat=np.arange(20, 50, 2)
lon=np.arange(-130, -60, 2.5)

ds['emis_NO']= xr.DataArray(np.random.random([len(lat), len(lon)]), dims=['lat','lon'])
ds['emis_NO2']= xr.DataArray(np.random.random([len(lat), len(lon)]), dims=['lat','lon'])
ds['emis_ISOP']= xr.DataArray(np.random.random([len(lat), len(lon)]), dims=['lat','lon'])
ds['emis_ACET']= xr.DataArray(np.random.random([len(lat), len(lon)]), dims=['lat','lon'])

# Get a list of the DataArrays I want to Sum in this DataSet, ds, matching a 
# string naming convention (Sum emissions of NOx = NO + NO2). 
vars2sum=  [x for x in ds.data_vars if ('emis_NO' in x)]

# What follows is my solution that works, that I'd like to condense 
# if possible in a more pythonic way: 
total= ds[vars2sum[0]].values * 0 # create something right size, fill w/ 0s 

for darr in vars2sum:             # Loop over variables to sum. 
   total= total+ ds[darr].values  # iteratively update total.
```

The desired output of this is equivalent to adding the DataArrays by hand as follows(assuming you know them all).

```
total= ds.emis_NO.values + ds.emis_NO2.values
```

I'm iterating within a function because the number of DataArrays I'm summing (that are caught with my str match) within a given DataSet varies from dataset to Dataset.

Comment: please try to provide the input you provide to this bit of code (the content of `ds` for example) and the output you expect at the end in your case the content you want in `total`

Comment: just concatenate them using ds=xr.concat([var_names], 'dumm') and do ds.sum('dumm')

Comment: Very related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149355/is-there-a-faster-way-to-sum-xarray-dataset-variables/65184257#65184257).

Answer (score 0):

You can first concatenate the selected variables along a new dimension using `to_array` (by default, the new dimension will be named `'variable'`). Then, sum along that dimension:

```py
ds[vars2sum].to_array().sum("variable")
```

Alternatively, you could use a list comprehension:

```py
sum([ds[var] for var in vars2sum])
```